# openstack trusty:liberty deployment fails due to no relations and insufficient peer units

Tags: 14.04, juju, maas, openstack

I'm currently trying to deploy an Openstack trusty-liberty cloud with juju (1.25.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1) in a KVM virtualized MAAS environment. To do so, I downloaded the openstack-base bundle from here: https://jujucharms.com/openstack-base/
Then modified each charm repo "charm: cs:XXX" to match the trusty release, changed the series to trusty and chose cloud:trusty-liberty as the openstack-origin.

Now what happens after "juju quickstart bundle.yaml --no-browser" is that deployment works, but relations are not established as well as some services do not get spawned. Apparently I have not enough peers defined in my MAAS env., but I currently have 6 VMs running:
1 for MAAS
1 for juju
4 Nodes (all defined in MAAS).
Additionally there is an other unused Node in MAAS, which is not being allocated at all.
Each VM has 2 NATed Networks (both are managed in MAAS), 8GB RAM, 1 Core, 60 + 20G HDD, VMX is forwarded to the machines.

My question now is: why does this fail?

I've attached my bundle.yaml, juju status and juju debug-log output.

bundle.yaml:

```
machines:   '0':
    constraints: arch=amd64
    series: trusty   '1':
    constraints: arch=amd64
    series: trusty   '2':
    constraints: arch=amd64
    series: trusty   '3':
    constraints: arch=amd64
    series: trusty relations:
- - nova-compute:amqp
  - rabbitmq-server:amqp
- - neutron-gateway:amqp
  - rabbitmq-server:amqp
- - keystone:shared-db
  - mysql:shared-db
- - nova-cloud-controller:identity-service
  - keystone:identity-service
- - glance:identity-service
  - keystone:identity-service
- - neutron-api:identity-service
  - keystone:identity-service
- - neutron-openvswitch:neutron-plugin-api
  - neutron-api:neutron-plugin-api
- - neutron-api:shared-db
  - mysql:shared-db
- - neutron-api:amqp
  - rabbitmq-server:amqp
- - neutron-gateway:neutron-plugin-api
  - neutron-api:neutron-plugin-api
- - glance:shared-db
  - mysql:shared-db
- - glance:amqp
  - rabbitmq-server:amqp
- - nova-cloud-controller:image-service
  - glance:image-service
- - nova-compute:image-service
  - glance:image-service
- - nova-cloud-controller:cloud-compute
  - nova-compute:cloud-compute
- - nova-cloud-controller:amqp
  - rabbitmq-server:amqp
- - nova-cloud-controller:quantum-network-service
  - neutron-gateway:quantum-network-service
- - nova-compute:neutron-plugin
  - neutron-openvswitch:neutron-plugin
- - neutron-openvswitch:amqp
  - rabbitmq-server:amqp
- - openstack-dashboard:identity-service
  - keystone:identity-service
- - nova-cloud-controller:shared-db
  - mysql:shared-db
- - nova-cloud-controller:neutron-api
  - neutron-api:neutron-api
- - cinder:image-service
  - glance:image-service
- - cinder:amqp
  - rabbitmq-server:amqp
- - cinder:identity-service
  - keystone:identity-service
- - cinder:cinder-volume-service
  - nova-cloud-controller:cinder-volume-service
- - cinder-ceph:storage-backend
  - cinder:storage-backend
- - ceph-mon:client
  - nova-compute:ceph
- - cinder:shared-db
  - mysql:shared-db
- - ceph-mon:client
  - cinder-ceph:ceph
- - ceph-mon:client
  - glance:ceph
- - ceph-osd:mon
  - ceph-mon:osd
- - ntp:juju-info
  - nova-compute:juju-info
- - ntp:juju-info
  - neutron-gateway:juju-info
- - ceph-radosgw:mon
  - ceph-mon:radosgw
- - ceph-radosgw:identity-service
  - keystone:identity-service series: trusty services:   ceph-mon:
    annotations:
      gui-x: '750'
      gui-y: '500'
    charm: cs:trusty/ceph-mon-6
    num_units: 3
    options:
      expected-osd-count: 3
    to:
    - lxc:1
    - lxc:2
    - lxc:3   ceph-osd:
    annotations:
      gui-x: '1000'
      gui-y: '500'
    charm: cs:trusty/ceph-osd-238
    num_units: 3
    options:
      osd-devices: /dev/sdb
      osd-reformat: 'yes'
    to:
    - '1'
    - '2'
    - '3'   ceph-radosgw:
    annotations:
      gui-x: '1000'
      gui-y: '250'
    charm: cs:trusty/ceph-radosgw-245
    num_units: 1
    options:
      use-embedded-webserver: true
    to:
    - lxc:0   cinder:
    annotations:
      gui-x: '750'
      gui-y: '0'
    charm: cs:trusty/cinder-257
    num_units: 1
    options:
      openstack-origin: cloud:trusty-liberty
      block-device: None
      glance-api-version: 2
    to:
    - lxc:1   cinder-ceph:
    annotations:
      gui-x: '750'
      gui-y: '250'
    charm: cs:trusty/cinder-ceph-221
    num_units: 0   glance:
    annotations:
      gui-x: '250'
      gui-y: '0'
    charm: cs:trusty/glance-253
    options:
      openstack-origin: cloud:trusty-liberty
    num_units: 1
    to:
    - lxc:2   keystone:
    annotations:
      gui-x: '500'
      gui-y: '0'
    charm: cs:trusty/keystone-258
    num_units: 1
    options:
      openstack-origin: cloud:trusty-liberty
      admin-password: openstack
    to:
    - lxc:3   mysql:
    annotations:
      gui-x: '0'
      gui-y: '250'
    charm: cs:trusty/percona-cluster-246
    num_units: 1
    options:
      max-connections: 20000
    to:
    - lxc:0   neutron-api:
    annotations:
      gui-x: '500'
      gui-y: '500'
    charm: cs:trusty/neutron-api-246
    num_units: 1
    options:
      openstack-origin: cloud:trusty-liberty
      flat-network-providers: physnet1
      neutron-security-groups: true
    to:
    - lxc:1   neutron-gateway:
    annotations:
      gui-x: '0'
      gui-y: '0'
    charm: cs:neutron-gateway-232
    num_units: 1
    options:
      openstack-origin: cloud:trusty-liberty
      bridge-mappings: physnet1:br-ex
      data-port: br-ex:eth1
    to:
    - '0'   neutron-openvswitch:
    annotations:
      gui-x: '250'
      gui-y: '500'
    charm: cs:trusty/neutron-openvswitch-238
    num_units: 0   nova-cloud-controller:
    annotations:
      gui-x: '0'
      gui-y: '500'
    charm: cs:trusty/nova-cloud-controller-292
    num_units: 1
    options:
      openstack-origin: cloud:trusty-liberty
      network-manager: Neutron
    to:
    - lxc:2   nova-compute:
    annotations:
      gui-x: '250'
      gui-y: '250'
    charm: cs:trusty/nova-compute-260
    num_units: 3
    options:
      openstack-origin: cloud:trusty-liberty
      enable-live-migration: true
      enable-resize: true
      migration-auth-type: ssh
    to:
    - '1'
    - '2'
    - '3'   ntp:
    annotations:
      gui-x: '1000'
      gui-y: '0'
    charm: cs:trusty/ntp-16
    num_units: 0   openstack-dashboard:
    annotations:
      gui-x: '500'
      gui-y: '-250'
    charm: cs:trusty/openstack-dashboard-243
    num_units: 1
    options:
      openstack-origin: cloud:trusty-liberty
    to:
    - lxc:3   rabbitmq-server:
    annotations:
      gui-x: '500'
      gui-y: '250'
    charm: cs:trusty/rabbitmq-server-56
    num_units: 1
    to:
    - lxc:0
```

juju status:

```
user@landscape14:~$ juju status
environment: maas
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.25.6
    dns-name: node1.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-c9483b6c-947e-11e6-8c9d-525400e2d38e/
    series: trusty
    containers:
      0/lxc/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.25.6
        dns-name: 192.168.55.211
        instance-id: juju-machine-0-lxc-0
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
      0/lxc/1:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.25.6
        dns-name: 192.168.55.212
        instance-id: juju-machine-0-lxc-1
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=8192M tags=node-c9483b6c-947e-11e6-8c9d-525400e2d38e
      availability-zone=default
    state-server-member-status: has-vote
  "1":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.25.6
    dns-name: node2.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-f4b6dd30-947e-11e6-bae8-525400e2d38e/
    series: trusty
    containers:
      1/lxc/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.25.6
        dns-name: 192.168.55.222
        instance-id: juju-machine-1-lxc-0
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
      1/lxc/1:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.25.6
        dns-name: 192.168.55.219
        instance-id: juju-machine-1-lxc-1
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
      1/lxc/2:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.25.6
        dns-name: 192.168.55.220
        instance-id: juju-machine-1-lxc-2
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=8192M tags=node-f4b6dd30-947e-11e6-bae8-525400e2d38e
      availability-zone=default
  "2":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.25.6
    dns-name: node4.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-215eebca-947f-11e6-88e7-525400e2d38e/
    series: trusty
    containers:
      2/lxc/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.25.6
        dns-name: 192.168.55.184
        instance-id: juju-machine-2-lxc-0
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=8192M tags=node-215eebca-947f-11e6-88e7-525400e2d38e
      availability-zone=default
  "3":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.25.6
    dns-name: node5.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-f1c003b4-955e-11e6-973c-525400e2d38e/
    series: trusty
    containers:
      3/lxc/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.25.6
        dns-name: 192.168.55.223
        instance-id: juju-machine-3-lxc-0
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=8192M tags=node-f1c003b4-955e-11e6-973c-525400e2d38e
      availability-zone=default
services:
  ceph-mon:
    charm: cs:trusty/ceph-mon-6
    exposed: false
    service-status:
      current: blocked
      message: Insufficient peer units to bootstrap cluster (require 3)
      since: 04 Nov 2016 09:09:45+01:00
    relations:
      mon:
      - ceph-mon
    units:
      ceph-mon/0:
        workload-status:
          current: blocked
          message: Insufficient peer units to bootstrap cluster (require 3)
          since: 04 Nov 2016 09:09:45+01:00
        agent-status:
          current: idle
          since: 04 Nov 2016 09:09:48+01:00
          version: 1.25.6
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.25.6
        machine: 1/lxc/0
        public-address: 192.168.55.222
  ceph-osd:
    charm: cs:trusty/ceph-osd-238
    exposed: false
    service-status:
      current: blocked
      message: 'Missing relation: monitor'
      since: 04 Nov 2016 09:08:48+01:00
    units:
      ceph-osd/0:
        workload-status:
          current: blocked
          message: 'Missing relation: monitor'
          since: 04 Nov 2016 09:08:48+01:00
        agent-status:
          current: idle
          since: 04 Nov 2016 09:08:51+01:00
          version: 1.25.6
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.25.6
        machine: "1"
        public-address: node2.maas
  ceph-radosgw:
    charm: cs:trusty/ceph-radosgw-245
    exposed: false
    service-status:
      current: blocked
      message: 'Missing relations: mon'
      since: 04 Nov 2016 09:09:32+01:00
    relations:
      cluster:
      - ceph-radosgw
    units:
      ceph-radosgw/0:
        workload-status:
          current: blocked
          message: 'Missing relations: mon'
          since: 04 Nov 2016 09:09:32+01:00
        agent-status:
          current: idle
          since: 04 Nov 2016 09:09:36+01:00
          version: 1.25.6
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.25.6
        machine: 0/lxc/0
        public-address: 192.168.55.211
  cinder:
    charm: cs:trusty/cinder-257
    exposed: false
    service-status:
      current: blocked
      message: 'Missing relations: messaging, identity, database'
      since: 04 Nov 2016 09:11:13+01:00
    relations:
      cluster:
      - cinder
    units:
      cinder/0:
        workload-status:
          current: blocked
          message: 'Missing relations: messaging, identity, database'
          since: 04 Nov 2016 09:11:13+01:00
        agent-status:
          current: idle
          since: 04 Nov 2016 09:11:18+01:00
          version: 1.25.6
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.25.6
        machine: 1/lxc/1
        open-ports:
        - 8776/tcp
        public-address: 192.168.55.219
  cinder-ceph:
    charm: cs:trusty/cinder-ceph-221
    exposed: false
    service-status: {}
  glance:
    charm: cs:trusty/glance-253
    exposed: false
    service-status:
      current: blocked
      message: 'Missing relations: identity, database'
      since: 04 Nov 2016 09:10:05+01:00
    relations:
      cluster:
      - glance
    units:
      glance/0:
        workload-status:
          current: blocked
          message: 'Missing relations: identity, database'
          since: 04 Nov 2016 09:10:05+01:00
        agent-status:
          current: idle
          since: 04 Nov 2016 09:10:08+01:00
          version: 1.25.6
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.25.6
        machine: 3/lxc/0
        open-ports:
        - 9292/tcp
        public-address: 192.168.55.223
  juju-gui:
    charm: cs:trusty/juju-gui-141
    exposed: true
    service-status:
      current: unknown
      since: 03 Nov 2016 22:10:01+01:00
    units:
      juju-gui/0:
        workload-status:
          current: unknown
          since: 03 Nov 2016 22:10:01+01:00
        agent-status:
          current: idle
          since: 04 Nov 2016 09:10:51+01:00
          version: 1.25.6
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.25.6
        machine: "0"
        open-ports:
        - 80/tcp
        - 443/tcp
        public-address: node1.maas
  keystone:
    charm: cs:trusty/keystone-258
    exposed: false
    service-status:
      current: blocked
      message: 'Missing relations: database'
      since: 04 Nov 2016 09:12:58+01:00
    relations:
      cluster:
      - keystone
    units:
      keystone/0:
        workload-status:
          current: blocked
          message: 'Missing relations: database'
          since: 04 Nov 2016 09:12:58+01:00
        agent-status:
          current: executing
          message: running update-status hook
          since: 04 Nov 2016 09:12:55+01:00
          version: 1.25.6
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.25.6
        machine: 2/lxc/0
        open-ports:
        - 5000/tcp
        public-address: 192.168.55.184
  mysql:
    charm: cs:trusty/percona-cluster-246
    exposed: false
    service-status:
      current: active
      message: Unit is ready
      since: 04 Nov 2016 09:09:58+01:00
    relations:
      cluster:
      - mysql
    units:
      mysql/0:
        workload-status:
          current: active
          message: Unit is ready
          since: 04 Nov 2016 09:09:58+01:00
        agent-status:
          current: idle
          since: 04 Nov 2016 09:10:02+01:00
          version: 1.25.6
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.25.6
        machine: 0/lxc/1
        public-address: 192.168.55.212
  neutron-api:
    charm: cs:trusty/neutron-api-246
    exposed: false
    service-status:
      current: blocked
      message: 'Missing relations: messaging, identity, database'
      since: 04 Nov 2016 09:08:49+01:00
    relations:
      cluster:
      - neutron-api
    units:
      neutron-api/0:
        workload-status:
          current: blocked
          message: 'Missing relations: messaging, identity, database'
          since: 04 Nov 2016 09:08:49+01:00
        agent-status:
          current: idle
          since: 04 Nov 2016 09:08:55+01:00
          version: 1.25.6
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.25.6
        machine: 1/lxc/2
        open-ports:
        - 9696/tcp
        public-address: 192.168.55.220
  neutron-openvswitch:
    charm: cs:trusty/neutron-openvswitch-238
    exposed: false
    service-status: {}
  ntp:
    charm: cs:trusty/ntp-16
    exposed: false
    service-status: {}
    relations:
      ntp-peers:
      - ntp
networks:
  subnet-1:
    provider-id: subnet-1
    cidr: 192.168.55.0/24
  subnet-2:
    provider-id: subnet-2
    cidr: 192.168.56.0/24
```

juju debug-log:

```
unit-keystone-0[940]: 2016-11-04 08:12:58 INFO unit.keystone/0.juju-log server.go:268 HAProxy context is incomplete, this unit has no peers.
unit-keystone-0[940]: 2016-11-04 08:12:58 WARNING unit.keystone/0.juju-log server.go:268 database relation is missing and must be related for functionality. 
unit-keystone-0[940]: 2016-11-04 08:12:59 INFO unit.keystone/0.juju-log server.go:268 Application Version: 8.1.2
unit-ceph-osd-0[31739]: 2016-11-04 08:13:49 DEBUG unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'install'
unit-ceph-osd-0[31739]: 2016-11-04 08:13:49 DEBUG unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'config_changed'
unit-ceph-osd-0[31739]: 2016-11-04 08:13:49 DEBUG unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'upgrade_charm'
unit-ceph-osd-0[31739]: 2016-11-04 08:13:49 DEBUG unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'update_status'
unit-ceph-osd-0[31739]: 2016-11-04 08:13:50 DEBUG unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log server.go:268 No hardening applied to 'update_status'
unit-ceph-osd-0[31739]: 2016-11-04 08:13:50 INFO unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log server.go:268 Updating status.
unit-ceph-osd-0[31739]: 2016-11-04 08:13:52 INFO unit.ceph-osd/0.juju-log server.go:268 Application Version: 0.80.11
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:13:56 INFO unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 Registered config file: /etc/neutron/neutron.conf
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:13:56 INFO unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 Registered config file: /etc/default/neutron-server
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:13:56 INFO unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 Registered config file: /etc/apache2/sites-available/openstack_https_frontend.conf
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:13:56 INFO unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 Registered config file: /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:13:56 INFO unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 Registered config file: /etc/neutron/neutron_lbaas.conf
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:13:57 INFO unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 Registered config file: /etc/neutron/neutron_vpnaas.conf
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:13:57 INFO unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 Registered config file: /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:13:57 DEBUG unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'install'
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:13:57 DEBUG unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'config_changed'
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:13:57 DEBUG unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'update_status'
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:13:57 DEBUG unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function '_harden_inner2'
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:13:57 DEBUG unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 No hardening applied to '_harden_inner2'
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:13:57 DEBUG unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 No hardening applied to 'update_status'
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:13:57 INFO unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 Updating status.
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:13:58 DEBUG unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 Generating template context for amqp
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:13:58 INFO unit.neutron-api/0.update-status logger.go:40 error: no relation id specified
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:13:58 DEBUG unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 Generating template context for identity-service
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:14:00 DEBUG unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 Ensuring haproxy enabled in /etc/default/haproxy.
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:14:00 INFO unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 HAProxy context is incomplete, this unit has no peers.
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:14:00 WARNING unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 messaging relation is missing and must be related for functionality. 
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:14:00 WARNING unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 identity relation is missing and must be related for functionality. 
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:14:00 WARNING unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 database relation is missing and must be related for functionality. 
unit-neutron-api-0[943]: 2016-11-04 08:14:03 INFO unit.neutron-api/0.juju-log server.go:268 Application Version: 7.2.0
unit-ceph-radosgw-0[942]: 2016-11-04 08:14:37 INFO unit.ceph-radosgw/0.juju-log server.go:268 Registered config file: /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
unit-ceph-radosgw-0[942]: 2016-11-04 08:14:37 INFO unit.ceph-radosgw/0.juju-log server.go:268 Registered config file: /etc/ceph/ceph.conf
unit-ceph-radosgw-0[942]: 2016-11-04 08:14:37 DEBUG unit.ceph-radosgw/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'install'
unit-ceph-radosgw-0[942]: 2016-11-04 08:14:37 DEBUG unit.ceph-radosgw/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'config_changed'
unit-ceph-radosgw-0[942]: 2016-11-04 08:14:37 DEBUG unit.ceph-radosgw/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'update_status'
unit-ceph-radosgw-0[942]: 2016-11-04 08:14:37 DEBUG unit.ceph-radosgw/0.juju-log server.go:268 No hardening applied to 'update_status'
unit-ceph-radosgw-0[942]: 2016-11-04 08:14:37 INFO unit.ceph-radosgw/0.juju-log server.go:268 Updating status.
unit-ceph-radosgw-0[942]: 2016-11-04 08:14:39 DEBUG unit.ceph-radosgw/0.juju-log server.go:268 Generating template context for identity-service
unit-ceph-radosgw-0[942]: 2016-11-04 08:14:39 DEBUG unit.ceph-radosgw/0.juju-log server.go:268 Ensuring haproxy enabled in /etc/default/haproxy.
unit-ceph-radosgw-0[942]: 2016-11-04 08:14:39 INFO unit.ceph-radosgw/0.juju-log server.go:268 HAProxy context is incomplete, this unit has no peers.
unit-ceph-radosgw-0[942]: 2016-11-04 08:14:39 WARNING unit.ceph-radosgw/0.juju-log server.go:268 mon relation is missing and must be related for functionality. 
unit-ceph-radosgw-0[942]: 2016-11-04 08:14:41 INFO unit.ceph-radosgw/0.juju-log server.go:268 Application Version: 0.80.11
unit-ceph-mon-0[947]: 2016-11-04 08:14:46 DEBUG unit.ceph-mon/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'install'
unit-ceph-mon-0[947]: 2016-11-04 08:14:46 DEBUG unit.ceph-mon/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'config_changed'
unit-ceph-mon-0[947]: 2016-11-04 08:14:46 DEBUG unit.ceph-mon/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'upgrade_charm'
unit-ceph-mon-0[947]: 2016-11-04 08:14:46 DEBUG unit.ceph-mon/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'update_status'
unit-ceph-mon-0[947]: 2016-11-04 08:14:46 DEBUG unit.ceph-mon/0.juju-log server.go:268 No hardening applied to 'update_status'
unit-ceph-mon-0[947]: 2016-11-04 08:14:46 INFO unit.ceph-mon/0.juju-log server.go:268 Updating status.
unit-ceph-mon-0[947]: 2016-11-04 08:14:49 INFO unit.ceph-mon/0.juju-log server.go:268 Application Version: 0.80.11
unit-mysql-0[940]: 2016-11-04 08:15:00 DEBUG unit.mysql/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'install'
unit-mysql-0[940]: 2016-11-04 08:15:00 DEBUG unit.mysql/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'upgrade'
unit-mysql-0[940]: 2016-11-04 08:15:00 DEBUG unit.mysql/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'config_changed'
unit-mysql-0[940]: 2016-11-04 08:15:00 DEBUG unit.mysql/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'update_status'
unit-mysql-0[940]: 2016-11-04 08:15:00 DEBUG unit.mysql/0.juju-log server.go:268 No hardening applied to 'update_status'
unit-mysql-0[940]: 2016-11-04 08:15:00 INFO unit.mysql/0.juju-log server.go:268 Updating status.
unit-mysql-0[940]: 2016-11-04 08:15:00 INFO unit.mysql/0.update-status logger.go:40  * Percona XtraDB Cluster up and running
unit-mysql-0[940]: 2016-11-04 08:15:00 INFO unit.mysql/0.juju-log server.go:268 Unit is ready
unit-mysql-0[940]: 2016-11-04 08:15:02 INFO unit.mysql/0.juju-log server.go:268 Application Version: 5.5.37-25.10+dfsg
unit-glance-0[918]: 2016-11-04 08:15:08 INFO unit.glance/0.juju-log server.go:268 Registered config file: /etc/glance/glance-registry.conf
unit-glance-0[918]: 2016-11-04 08:15:08 INFO unit.glance/0.juju-log server.go:268 Registered config file: /etc/glance/glance-api.conf
unit-glance-0[918]: 2016-11-04 08:15:08 INFO unit.glance/0.juju-log server.go:268 Registered config file: /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
unit-glance-0[918]: 2016-11-04 08:15:08 INFO unit.glance/0.juju-log server.go:268 Registered config file: /etc/apache2/sites-available/openstack_https_frontend.conf
unit-glance-0[918]: 2016-11-04 08:15:08 DEBUG unit.glance/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'install_hook'
unit-glance-0[918]: 2016-11-04 08:15:08 DEBUG unit.glance/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'config_changed'
unit-glance-0[918]: 2016-11-04 08:15:08 DEBUG unit.glance/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'upgrade_charm'
unit-glance-0[918]: 2016-11-04 08:15:08 DEBUG unit.glance/0.juju-log server.go:268 Hardening function 'update_status'
unit-glance-0[918]: 2016-11-04 08:15:08 DEBUG unit.glance/0.juju-log server.go:268 No hardening applied to 'update_status'
unit-glance-0[918]: 2016-11-04 08:15:08 INFO unit.glance/0.juju-log server.go:268 Updating status.
unit-glance-0[918]: 2016-11-04 08:15:08 INFO unit.glance/0.update-status logger.go:40 error: no relation id specified
unit-glance-0[918]: 2016-11-04 08:15:08 DEBUG unit.glance/0.juju-log server.go:268 Generating template context for amqp
unit-glance-0[918]: 2016-11-04 08:15:08 DEBUG unit.glance/0.juju-log server.go:268 Generating template context for identity-service
unit-glance-0[918]: 2016-11-04 08:15:08 DEBUG unit.glance/0.juju-log server.go:268 0 section(s) found
unit-glance-0[918]: 2016-11-04 08:15:08 DEBUG unit.glance/0.juju-log server.go:268 Generating template context for identity-service
unit-glance-0[918]: 2016-11-04 08:15:08 DEBUG unit.glance/0.juju-log server.go:268 Ensuring haproxy enabled in /etc/default/haproxy.
unit-glance-0[918]: 2016-11-04 08:15:08 WARNING unit.glance/0.juju-log server.go:268 identity relation is missing and must be related for functionality. 
unit-glance-0[918]: 2016-11-04 08:15:09 WARNING unit.glance/0.juju-log server.go:268 database relation is missing and must be related for functionality. 
unit-glance-0[918]: 2016-11-04 08:15:10 INFO unit.glance/0.juju-log server.go:268 Application Version: 11.0.1
```

I'm thankful for any input :)

update:
I installed the rest of the services manually with juju deploy (always referencing cs:trusty/XXX. It seems though that Icehouse has been installed and not liberty.... >_>

Comment: I don't see any issue with your bundle. The indentation issues would probably be due to pasting it here. One thing i would suggest, regarding 'missing relations', is manually removing mysql unit and add it again. $ juju remove-unit mysql/0

Comment: and then $ juju add-unit mysql --to lxc:0

Comment: thanks, I basically did what you suggested and manually installed the rest. I still dont understand why I my bundle does not create the relations and full deployment though... In addition it seems icehouse has been installed and not the liberty release from the cloud-archive, which I referenced in my config as well. Any idea why?